# Android Studio My Button on the second Activity doesn't Work

Tags: java, android

I think it a very easy Question. I am new to Android Studio and I could not find an answer.

I have an activity that switches per Button to another activity. However, on my second activity, my simple Button just to change the Textview which doesn't work.

Layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".StartActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/twText"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="127dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="127dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="88dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="127dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="127dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="624dp"
        android:text="Ihr Passwort war Richtig!"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent" />


    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnChecke"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginStart="134dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="134dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="32dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="189dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="189dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="371dp"
        android:text="Check"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
        />

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

`onCreate` method in my second activity

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    tw = findViewById(R.id.twText);
    btnCheck = findViewById(R.id.btnChecke);

    btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            tw.setText("work");
        }
    });
}
```

And this is how I am starting the second activity (`onCreate` method from my first activity).

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_start);

    tw = findViewById(R.id.twText);
    Button btnCheck = findViewById(R.id.btnChecke);

    btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            setContentView("Work"R.layout.activity_main);
        }
    });
}
```

I have checked the variable names in the layout and looks like everything is fine.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Can you please post the layout and the `onCreate` function of your second activity? Thanks.

Comment: I updated my Question. Does it help with my GitHub link?

Comment: You may post your Github link. However, your question should be sufficient enough for the other developers to help you.

Comment: I think the previous edit was actually having the problem. Please see my answer below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**This answer is based on the problem which I found before the latest edit from the OP. Here is the [version of the edit](https://stackoverflow.com/revisions/66e3e19e-261a-4904-9a2a-b44a39295a16/view-source) where I found the problem.**

First of all, something is very wrong about the `onClickListener` of your button. You are setting the content view again, instead of starting your second activity. It looks like, you are just setting the content view of your `StartActivity` which actually does not launch the `MainActivity` that you are trying to start.

In order to start a new activity, you need to add the following in your button `onClickListener`.

```
btnCheck.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // setContentView(R.layout.activity_main); // This is not the way for starting another activity 

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, MainActivity.class); 
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Once your `MainActivity` has started, you should be able to change the text with no problem.

Comment: I think this is my main Problem. Sorry i tried to do something  and uploaded the false code. But i try to launch the ssecond Activity just to use setContentView() . The next  Problem is when i try to declare the Inten i get this Intent intent = new Intent(this,StartActivity.class)
                    StartActivity(intent);

Comment: From the android point of view, you cannot launch an `Activity` using the `setContentView` only. You are just changing the layout of the current activity using `setContentView`. I have stated the proper way of launching the second activity which you may follow if you need to launch the second activity.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bundle bundle = getIntent().getExtras()
if(bundle.getString("changeTextView")
TextView .... = (TextView) ....setText();
```

Hi. If I good understand, you should use Intent with "putExtra()".
Exmple:`intent.putExtras("changeTextView");`
After that in your onCreate() method you can put: